# Using wmd-new to submit markdown

Tags: markdown, wmd, wmd-editor

Does anyone use the [wmd-new editor](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/source/list) posted on google code?

I've installed the editor and got it to work correctly. I thought the editor would submit raw markdown. To my surprise it submits HTML. This is a problem because I need to store a markdown version of the text.

Another issue is, if there's a validation error, the form will reload with HTML instead of the original markdown. This would puzzle users unfamiliar with HTML.

Any ideas how to get it to submit raw markdown, or HTML and markdown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML back to Markdown for editing in wmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235224/convert-html-back-to-markdown-for-editing-in-wmd).

Comment: @Chris, while that question does not have my answer (there's no such file as referenced in the answer), I did find another post with the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097917/cant-seem-to-save-the-markup-version-of-the-text-using-wmd-editor

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097917/cant-seem-to-save-the-markup-version-of-the-text-using-wmd-editor), the option can be set below the text area using the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    wmd_options = {
        output: "Markdown"
    };

</script>
```